# Alarm Manager : How to Call Alarm Manager at particular time?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I wanted to know How I can set Alarm for a particular time. For example I want to set alarm for
morning 9am daily. I googled a lot but found only the way to set alarm for a given interval only. like after 2 hours or next day.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this code helps you

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

//9 AM 
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, YourClass.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

you should create [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to receive intent.

read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for further details

Answer (score 0):

> I googled a lot but found only the way to set alarm for a given interval only. like after 2 hours or next day.

The second parameter to `setRepeating()` on `AlarmManager` is when you want the alarm to go off first. Set that to be 9am tomorrow using a Calendar object, and use an `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm.