# difference between RTC and RTC_WAKEUP in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-alarms

i am new to android i have to perform some operation after every 30 min whether my application is running or not so i want to how to perform these operation using service and alarm manager any example or running will be helpfull

Comment: here is complete answer  :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use RTC_WAKEUP if you want your service to perform some operation every 30 min as RTC_WAKEUP will wake the device up and deliver the pending intent.
On the other hand RTC will deliver the intent only when the device wakes up.

Comment: what do you mean by weak_up ? when the screen turns on?

Comment: refer to sagar, what do you mean by weak_up ? when the screen turns on?

Comment: @SagarNayak According this, https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-3-working-in-the-background/lesson-8-alarms-and-schedulers/8-2-c-alarms/8-2-c-alarms.html, wake up mean wake up cpu.

Comment: @ShivamSharma According this, https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-3-working-in-the-background/lesson-8-alarms-and-schedulers/8-2-c-alarms/8-2-c-alarms.html, wake up mean wake up cpu.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything you need to know is in the docs on [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

There can be many pitfalls trying to keep the phone awake, also see [cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) by Mark Murphy on github