# Android | Run command programmatically

Tags: android

I would like to create a (test) app that executes a command every hour in the background (for example, edit a file or show a debug message).

Assuming that the app starts with system boot

- How can I do this?
- The app must remain running always?

Comment: *The app must remain running always* good luck with that. A user can terminate your app whenever he wants to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute one task every hour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630365/how-to-execute-one-task-every-hour)

Comment: I expressed myself badly, I mean that the app should NOT remain in the background, it was a question. Sorry for duplicate, I didn't find that argument.

Answer (score 0):

Please use alarmmanager using service functionality to achieve this.

for eg:

```
private void setAlarmManager() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long l = new Date().getTime();
    if (l < new Date().getTime()) {
        l += 86400000; // start at next 24 hour
    }
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 86400000, sender); // 86400000
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10630571/1843331)

Comment: Instead of copy pasting an answer, just flag for duplicate

Comment: Intention is not copy paste. answer exact point to avoid time consuming

Comment: What is "sender"? I would to check some variables and execute a function/script..

Answer (score -1):

To Make your app start up when the devices boot completes You have to create a Class that extends Receiver.
In the manifest Declare your class like this

```
<receiver android:name=".ClassName">
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And don't forget to use the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Write the following to your Receiver class, onReceive Override method

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

If you want to Run something in your background use [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: OP doesn't want to know how to start his app on boot --> *Assuming that the app starts with system boot*

Comment: Then kindly down vote the question bro Not my answer please.... You know everything that doesn't mean our answers are wrong and eligible for downvoting...

Comment: If your answer doesn't address the problem in the question, it's "not useful" which makes it eligible for downvoting. Of course you can misinterpret the question and give a wrong answer, I do that myself some times. In that case I just admit my mistake and delete my answer. You are free to do as you like of course

Comment: I mean to say that you are not downvoting the answers that was copied from duplicated question even you already gave the source.. But u did mine....But anyway Thanks for the info....

Comment: Because that other answer does address the question, I consider it useful, even though it was copied from another answer (so I didn't upvote either). I hope you understand my reasoning

Comment: Yah sure... We are new at stackoverflow... You are Senior then us... Thanks... I understood...