# Alarm Manager does not execute broadcaster class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying out alarms and have hit a wall. I don't think my alarm is setting up properly because I never get a confirmation after the alarm is supposed to go off. Here's how I call on the alarm manager:

```
long alarmtime=new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;//run after 10 seconds
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmman = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmman.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms

        alarmman.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                alarmtime, 10 * 1000, pi);//run every 10 seconds
```

And here's my AlarmReceiver.java:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "TEST",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

}
```

However, the TEST text does not appear, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` argument, your initial alarm-time should be base on the elapsed real time of the device:

```
long alarmtime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 1000;
alarmman.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, alarmtime, 10 * 1000, pi);
```

(see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup)).

For a `BroadcastReceiver` it's probably `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` instead of `PendingIntent.getService()`. You are also cancelling the alarm, just update your `PendingIntent` like this and try not cancelling before:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) thoroughly for further information.

Comment: Just tried it, and it's not working either. I'm not even getting any error messages.

Comment: See my edit regarding the cancelling. If this doesn't work try registering the receiver in your manifest, but other than that everything else is correct.. try not triggering a toast, debug instead or print to the logcat to be sure.

Comment: I used log.w in alarmreceiver.java but it doesn't show up in logcat, which proves that it isn't opening.

Comment: Based on your code, this is all help I can give you, it should work this way. Like I said read the docs thoroughly, see if you missed anything in your code, pay attention to when you are triggering this alarm (app lifecycle), debug to see if you reach that code etc. Also you could try not using elapsed realtime but the normal wake-up based on your current time!

Comment: Thanks. I'll let you know if I figure it out somehow :p

Comment: Turns out in my manifest I typed in <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" /> instead of <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
............BRB GONNA GO KILL MYSELF IN THE MOST BRUTAL WAY POSSIBLE

Comment: Since you had to errors in your code anyway it wasn't for nothing. ;) Good to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the BroadcastReceiver is being called by doing a `System.out.println("TEST");` instead of Toast. If you are able to see that in your logcat, then the problem probably is that you need to run the Toast in UI thread.

Comment: Logcat's empty after trying with the println.