# What is the difference between RTC and RTC_WAKEUP of AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hello I was reading on android docs about these two constans of `AlarmManager` but didn't get exactly the difference between them.

> RTC   Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC).
>
> RTC_WAKEUP    Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC), which will wake up the device when it goes off.

Does not `RTC` wake up the device and fire the `PendingIntent` when device is in sleeping mode ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AlarmManager - RTC\_WAKEUP vs ELAPSED\_REALTIME\_WAKEUP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does not RTC wake up the device and fire the PendingIntent when device is in sleeping mode ?

`RTC` and `ELAPSED_REALTIME` do not wake up the device out of sleep mode. If the device is in sleep mode at the time of the event, nothing immediately happens. You will be notified about missed events when the device wakes up for other reasons (e.g., user presses the power button).

`RTC_WAKEUP` and `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` will wake up the device out of sleep mode. If your `PendingIntent` is a broadcast `PendingIntent`, Android will keep the device awake long enough for `onReceive()` to complete. If you have significant work, that you do not want to do in `onReceive()` (because `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread), you will need to arrange to keep the device awake long enough for some service of yours to complete the work, such as by using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: When I am running service from BroadcastReciever then Should I use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` in those cases ?

Comment: @Williams: If you are using a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm, and you want the device to stay awake while your service processes some transaction, then yes.

Comment: If I don't do then what will happen ?

Comment: @Williams: The device may fall back asleep before you finish your work.

Comment: Yup, Suppose I am doing network operation there and device fall back asleep then Will this network operation fail or success ?

Comment: @Williams: In all likelihood, it will fail.

Comment: ok thanks :). Suppose I have started a service from the activity and scheduled it every 4 hours using AlarmManager then How do I wake up and fallback back asleep device after code execution of service. I am not using here any WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: @Williams: "How do I wake up and fallback back asleep device after code execution of service" -- use `AlarmManager`, a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and an `IntentService`.

Comment: So when I want to do any periodic network work in service then I should use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` with `IntentService` not direct `IntentService` right ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, your nice answers always helpful. :) +1

Comment: The `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is deprecated starting from Android 8. But we can use the simple `BroadcastReceiver` instead and schedule a job with `JobScheduler` or `WorkManager` in the `onReceive()` method.