# Android Alarm manager is repeating after 5 seconds and ignoring interval time

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager

I am working on a widget application where I have to perform some task in every one minute. So, I am using AlarmManager to achieve this. But no matter whatever I set the interval time, its being repeated in every 5 seconds.

I am using AlarmManager like this:

```
 final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
        long interval = 60000;
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` is used to trigger the alarm since system boot time. Whereas `AlarmManager.RTC` uses UTC time.

```
 alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

This will start running **after system boots** and repeats at the specified interval.

```
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

This will start running **from now** and repeats at the specified interval.

To solve the problem, I suggest using `AlarmManager.RTC`. In case you want to start the alarm after 1 minute and then repeat, then pass the second param like this:

```
calendar.getTimeInMillis() + interval
```

Also check out the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5938497/5722608) for more explanation in Alarms.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding interval to second param (i.e. triggerAtMillis) worked for me.

Comment: Just to add ;) , AlarmManager.RTC , This alarm does not wake the device up; if it goes off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until the next time the device wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
    60000, 
    pendingIntent
);
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my device (Nexus5 cm13), it can work well
using below code :

```
    private void doWork() {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 0);
        final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
        long interval = 60000;
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
            interval, pendingIntent);
   }
```

So I don't know it clearly, and you can try "setRepeating" for testing.

Comment: I am using MotoG3 having API level 23. I tried using both (i.e. setRepeating() and setInexactRepeating()) but I was facing same issue. Answer given by FAЯAƸ worked for me. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, and i solve it by removing the

```
android:exported="true"
```

from my receiver in the Manifest, because this attribut make your receiver to receive messages from sources outside its application, check this link [android receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)