# Notification with AlertManager

Tags: android, notifications

My intention is to create a simple alarm after 8 second, but I can not talk to the class that extends **BroadcastReceiver**.
File AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlertNotification" />
```

File first.java:

```
long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 8 * 1000;
Log.d( "alarm", "started "+ Long.toString( time ) );
Intent NotificationAlert = new Intent( context, AlertNotification.class );
AlarmManager alarmManager = ( AlarmManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
alarmManager.set(
               AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
               time,
               PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0, NotificationAlert, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT )
);
```

File AlertNotification.java:

```
public class AlertNotification extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ){

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                new Intent( context, PersonalPage.class ),
                0
        );

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( context );

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon( R.drawable.shopify )
                .setContentTitle( "title" )
                .setContentText( "date" )
                .setDefaults( NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND )
                .setContentIntent( pIntent );

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = ( NotificationManager )
                context.getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );

        Log.d( "alarm", "true" );

        mNotificationManager.notify( 0, mBuilder.build() );

    }
}
```

The log *alarm* into first.java file is executed.
Log *alarm* into AlertNotification.java not.

**RESOLVED**

Comment: `Log.d( "alarm", "true" );` must be in the `onReceive()` method. Infact, the whole notification code must be there.

Comment: log is in the  `onReceive()` method

Comment: I am sorry. My bad. So code inside the `onReceive()` is not working. Is this your problem?.

Comment: yes, Maybe I'm wrong into PendingIntent in **Firs.java** file

Comment: Wait for at least a minute.

Comment: `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`= Time since you turn on the phone.thanks this is the error.now use `RTC_WAKEUP`= time phone clock.rightly so?

Comment: **Log alarm into AlertNotification.java** may not be executing because the receiver might not be getting the event it is registered for(alarm in this case). Wait at least for 1 minute instead of 8 seconds.

Comment: For such short period of time it is better to use Handler or countdowntimer

Comment: now use RTC_WAKEUP= time phone clock.rightly so? -- Yes. check this link too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup

Comment: Is it working now??

Comment: yes `RTC_WAKEUP` is the solution. thanks

Comment: Please accept my answer when  I write one. I have been banned from asking questions on StackOverflow. So accepted answers will help me in revoking my ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RTC_WAKEUP` instead of `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

If you want to use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` use following code

```
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
        8 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

*SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()* returns milliseconds since boot time.