# Alarm Manage Issue

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My app has repeating tasks will be running every 5-minutes. I try to install same app twice and then the Alarm Manager don't fire to the broadcast for doing the task.

First time install it working all the time, until I reinstall the same version it stop repeating task. This is the problem with Alarm Manager. I don't get it.

This is my code:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheckingPriceReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("com.abccompany.trading");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
    REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long mInterval = 300000;
    long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mInterval;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, mInterval, pendingIntent);
```

I don't know how to fix it. Please help!!~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this answer,
[Android Alarm What is the difference between four types of Alarm that AlarmManager provides and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102073/android-alarm-what-is-the-difference-between-four-types-of-alarm-that-alarmmanag)

Also this tells the difference in the types of Alarms,
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

**ELAPSED_REALTIME**

It will trigger since the boot time. Say if you set to 300000 then the alarm will trigger every 5 minutes and will not take the current time in consideration.

**RTC**

It will trigger as per the clock time meaning does not take boot time in consideration and will trigger at time as specified.

To wake up your device use this,

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerTime, mInterval, pendingIntent);
```

else use this if you don't want to wake up the device

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, triggerTime, mInterval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I have try both are not working to my needs. Thanks Bat Cat.

Comment: Kind of crazy of the Alarm Manager. Years I have seem this problem. Android team still have not look into it.

Comment: Alarm Manager is not reliable!!!